# Failing one test for Ceaser Cypher Encrpytor online judge

Tags: java

Hello friends I am using online judge for practice

I try this question for a long time to try pass all tests but it is failing 1 test

Here is the code

```
public static String caesarCypherEncryptor(String str, int key) {
    char[] newLetters = new char[str.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        int newLetterCode = str.charAt(i) + key;
        if (newLetterCode <= 122) {
            newLetters[i] = (char)(newLetterCode);
        } else {
            newLetters[i] = (char)(96 + newLetterCode % 122);
        }
    }
    return new String(newLetters);
}
```

Please point me in direction of want is reason for fail test

Comment: There's no test here.

Comment: Can you share the failing test?

Comment: Please make a [mcve] and show the example test case from the challenge. Explain whether you know the failing test case. If yes, please show it.

Comment: Think about what will happen when the passed in `key` is large enough such that `newLetterCode % 122` is greater than `26`.

Comment: @Mureinik Online judges usually do not provide the failing test case. The program is supposed to be written according to description, not according to test cases.

Comment: @Yunnosch the description isn't given either. So other than guessing what the problem is, there's nothing much we can do here.

Comment: @Mureinik I cannot see test case it is hidden.

Comment: Description is Ceaser Cypher Encryptor only lowercase string provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what will happen when the passed in `key` is large enough such that `newLetterCode % 122` is greater than `26`.

`newLetters[i]` will not be a lowercase ASCII letter, right? Because the ASCII code for `z` is 122.

An easy fix for this is to simply change the line:

```
int newLetterCode = str.charAt(i) + key;
```

to

```
int newLetterCode = str.charAt(i) + key % 26;
```

This will prevent `newLetterCode` from ever being greater than 147. Which means `newLetters[i]` will always be a letter within `a-z` which your code currently is not enforcing.